# Import providers from a sibling module in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have the following module structure in my Angular 2 project:

```
  app
   |-module1
   |-module2
        |-component2-1
        |-component2-2
        |-factories
```

The factories module has several providers defined as follows:

```js
@NgModule({
    providers: [                               
        { provide: Class1,          
          useFactory: Class1Factory,
          deps: [SameModuleDependency],          
          multi: true                       
        },
        { provide: Class2,
          useFactory: Class2Factory
        }
    ]
})

export function Class1Factory(): Class1 { ... }

export function Class2Factory(): Class2 { ... }
```

Suppose I want to make these factory providers available to component 2-1 and 2-2 in module 2. How should I import them in the module 2's module definition? I haven't found any example of these.

I guess that if I export each provider individually doing something like this:

```js
Class1Provider: Provider = {provide: Class1, useFactory: ... }
Class2Provider: Provider = {provide: Class2, useFactory: ....}
```

And then in module2 definition I can declare them:

```js
import { Class1Provider, Class2Provider } ....

@NgModule({

  providers: [Class1Provider, Class2Provider]

})
```

However, I haven't found a way to make this work (exporting instances, not class definitions)

Besides, I expect several providers, and not all of them been used by all sibling components, so I would prefer not to export/import each individually.

Bonus question: what if I want to make it available in module1's components?

Comment: are any of the modules participate in lazy routing?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com presently, not. I don't expect to be so any time soon.

Comment: _The factories module has several **modules** defined as follows_ - what do you mean by `modules` here?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com a mistake. i corrected it. Sorry

Comment: and here `I have the following module structure` by `module` you mean `angular modules`?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com yes, these are angular modules and components.

Comment: where are `Class1` and `Class1` defined?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com elsewhere, depends. these classes are imported by all the modules that require them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you defined providers in only module like this:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [                               
        { provide: Class1,          
          useFactory: Class1Factory,
          deps: [SameModuleDependency],          
          multi: true                       
        },
        { provide: Class2,
          useFactory: Class2Factory
        }
    ]
})
export class FactoriesModule {}
```

It's enough to import `FactoriesModule` into a root module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FactoryModule   <---------------------
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and so components will be able to inject the providers using relevant tokens:

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor(service: Class1) {}
```

This is because providers from all modules are merged during compilation.

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyctkh).

I highly suggest to read: [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f) article that explains the details

Comment: @angularindepth-com I tried this solution and it doesn't work. If I export the Class1Factory in the factory module  and move the providers definition to module2. it works. Therefore, looks like providers are not being merged.

Comment: they are definitely merged, read the article. create a stackblitz demo, I'll take a look

Comment: @angularindepth-com I replicated the problem with this toy application. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yv5mpq

In my local setup I get this error: 

zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Class1! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for Class1!

Comment: Apparently I didn't save the latest version of the project. Sorry for that.

Comment: @angularindepth-com I updated the project with a copy of the project I'm testing locally.

Comment: @pablochacin, you need to import `FactoryModule` into the `AppModule`. See [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyctkh) and my updated answer. Let me know if it works for you.